# Tradacoms integration with Mule

Tags: mule, tradacoms

Hi for a B2B integration scenario we are trying to use Mulesoft. Found out that Mulesoft doesn't support Tradacoms which is an old EDI format. Wanted to know if there are any 3rd party application or plugins that will help me do it.

Regards
Krishna

Comment: I worked with new EDI 850's but not Tradacoms. Have you looked at writing custom ESL and try? https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-b2b/edi-schema-language-reference

Comment: If you are willing to write dotnet code there is [Edi.Net](https://github.com/indice-co/EDI.Net) library that supports TRADACOMS and its opensource. Some info on executing dotnet code with mulesoft [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dotnet-connector-user-guide) _*Disclaimer I wrote the thing_